# Stuck in error 2 with mysql using XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to make a webpage using XAMPP with apache and MySQL after that I will use WordPress for creating the web page.
I have a problem creating the hostname and defining the user privileges at XAMPP.
The error 2 is constantly appearing while I try to define the user privileges:

> Can't read dir of 'C:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin\' (errno: 2 "No such file
>   or directory")

Can someone help and guide me for solving this problem

Comment: does the folder/file exist?

Comment: No it doesen't exist how can I import the missing files

Comment: how about i upload my copy?

Comment: Try my copy of plugin folder. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-RzJbMhCH0xUVYtNjhia1RXaG8/view?usp=sharing
and ofcourse virus scan: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/64f1ef4c852119cadd57907d1ef830bf72c7b4d97dc7cbd2cf36cde679b8b666/analysis/1486371377/

Comment: Again the same error :(

Comment: try running with run as administrator :|

Answer (score 63):

Just create the missing folders `C:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin\` and it should work.

I had the same issue when creating new `mysql` users in `PHPMyAdmin` after downloading the `XAMP 5.6.30` package. Creating the two missing empty folders worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem inspired by the above answer. My error was "mysqld.exe: File '.\mysql-bin.000093' not found (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")"

So I post it here as a help anyone.

I disabled MySQL replication setup within my.ini file. 
If you've set any "bin.log" configuration, in this case, you should disable it get MySQL server up.