# Error #1018 MySQL when i create a new user

Tags: php

I want to create a new user for MySql database but when I create a new user with `phpmyadmin` I get an error.

On executing the SQL query:

```
SHOW PLUGINS SONAME LIKE '%_PASSWORD_CHECK%'
```

I am getting the error:

> #1018 - Can't read dir of 'C:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin\' (errno: 2 "No such file or directory")

Comment: This is a phpmyadmin bug,upgrade it to the latest version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stuck in error 2 with mysql using XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063434/stuck-in-error-2-with-mysql-using-xampp)

Answer (score 20):

This problem arises because the folder doesn't exist. You need to first create the folder `C:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin\`, and then try to create the user again.

Regards,
C.