# why i am adding new user to phpmyadmin in xampp i am geetting error

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

[when trying to add user In phpmyadmin I m getting error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plavP.png)

when I am trying add a neww user I am unable add pls help me add a user, I have added the link of error what I got

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063434/stuck-in-error-2-with-mysql-using-xampp

Comment: Don't post errors as images. Don't use titles like "getting error" that are mostly useless for anyone trying to search the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stuck in error 2 with mysql using XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063434/stuck-in-error-2-with-mysql-using-xampp)